# Split a time duration row by 24 hour period and calculate hours for each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID | STARTDATE                | ENDDATE                  | Status
---+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------
1  | 2024-02-01 08:00:00.000  | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000  | a
1  | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000  | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000  | b
1  | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000  | 2024-02-07 08:15:00.000  | c
```

and I want to query to get an output that looks like this:

```
ID | STARTDATE                | ENDDATE                 | Status
---+--------------------------+-------------------------+--------
1  | 2024-02-01 08:00:00.000  | 2024-02-02 00:00:00.000 | a 
1  | 2024-02-02 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000 | a
1  | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000  | 2024-02-03 00:00:00.000 | b
1  | 2024-02-03 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-04 00:00:00.000 | b
1  | 2024-02-04 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-05 00:00:00.000 | b
1  | 2024-02-05 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000 | b 
1  | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000  | 2024-02-06 00:00:00.000 | c
1  | 2024-02-06 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-07 00:00:00.000 | c
1  | 2024-02-07 00:00:00.000  | 2024-02-07 08:15:00.000 | c
```

How can I achieve this with an Oracle SQL query?

I am not the best in Oracle, and have not seen a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query to iterate day-by-day:

```sql
WITH days (id, startdate, enddate, maxdate, status) AS (
  SELECT id,
         startdate,
         LEAST(
           CAST(TRUNC(startdate) + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS TIMESTAMP),
           enddate
         ),
         enddate,
         status
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         enddate,
         LEAST(
           enddate + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           maxdate
         ),
         maxdate,
         status
  FROM   days
  WHERE  enddate < maxdate
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id, status SET order_id
SELECT id, startdate, enddate, status
FROM   days
```

Or you can generate the rows using a `LATERAL` join to a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT id,
       GREATEST(
         startdate,
         CAST(TRUNC(startdate) + day AS TIMESTAMP)
       ) AS startdate,
       LEAST(
         enddate,
         CAST(TRUNC(startdate) + day + 1 AS TIMESTAMP)
       ) AS enddate,
       status
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS day
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(enddate) - TRUNC(startdate) + 1
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, Status) AS
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-02-01 08:00:00.000', TIMESTAMP '2024-02-02 10:30:00.000', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-02-02 10:30:00.000', TIMESTAMP '2024-02-05 14:20:00.000', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-02-05 14:20:00.000', TIMESTAMP '2024-02-07 08:15:00.000', 'c' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 08:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-02 00:00:00.000000000 | a |
| 1 | 2024-02-02 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000000000 | a |
| 1 | 2024-02-02 10:30:00.000000000 | 2024-02-03 00:00:00.000000000 | b |
| 1 | 2024-02-03 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-04 00:00:00.000000000 | b |
| 1 | 2024-02-04 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-05 00:00:00.000000000 | b |
| 1 | 2024-02-05 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000000000 | b |
| 1 | 2024-02-05 14:20:00.000000000 | 2024-02-06 00:00:00.000000000 | c |
| 1 | 2024-02-06 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-07 00:00:00.000000000 | c |
| 1 | 2024-02-07 00:00:00.000000000 | 2024-02-07 08:15:00.000000000 | c |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sd8i5F2C)